# How in SQL do i get only the entries where the same value is in a single column for the whole table?

Tags: mysql, sql

So im stuck on trying to make an SQL that grabs every ROW who has the same value for a specific COLUMN.

EXAMPLE:
                                                                                           table: buyers

```
aID | bID                        aID | bID
 1  |  3                          1  |  3 
 1  |  4                          1  |  2
 1  |  2                          2  |  2
 1  |  5                          1  |  4    this one also should return aID = 1
                                       since aID =1 is present for every different bID
```

I think I'm close with:

```
SELECT aID
  FROM buyers
 WHERE COUNT(bID) = (SELECT S1.aID
                       FROM buyers S1, 
                            buyers S2
                      WHERE S1.aID = S2.bID
                        AND S2.bID <> S1.bID)
```

it has to be in every row in a column or dont get it so if one `aID` was different then dont get it. an `aID` has to be matched to every `bID`

Comment: mySQL  database systems

Comment: I don't understand.  What would want the results to be for your query given the four rows in your example?  Why are you using `count()` function ? Your query does not make sense as written, but I cannot even guess what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want the aID if and only if it is present in every single ROW of the table

Comment: Then, given your example, you want the value `1` ???  But that "rule" has nothing to do with the values in bId, or with matching aId to bId... In your sample data,  the value `1` is not in `bId` in any of the 4 rows.  I still don't get it.

Comment: yes since it is in every row for that column but if there was another bID = 6 with aID 2 then it should not get any. since there is no aID that is present in every row

Comment: @keithzoller Can you edit your question with some raw data (where you have the original *unfiltered* data), and then show a sample of how you want it to look *after* filtering?

Comment: Then what are you talking about in "Matching aId to bId" ? What difference does it make what is in bId ??

Comment: i put up another example maybe that will help

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT aID
FROM buyers
GROUP BY aID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(distinct bID) FROM buyers)
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2905/1)

This assumes that every `aID,bID` combination is unique. If `bID` can be repeated for the same `aID`, you need to do:

```
SELECT aID
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT aID, bID FROM buyers)
GROUP BY aID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(distinct bID) FROM buyers)
```

Comment: If bID is not destinct in general or with relation to aID?

Comment: This should work as long as `bID` is distinct with relation to `aID`. If not, you need to use a subquery `(select distinct aID, bID from buyers)` in place of the first `buyers`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Select Distinct aId 
From Table t
Where Not Exists
   (Select * From table i
    Where bId <> t.bId
       And Not Exists 
           (Select * From table
            Where bId = i.bId
              And aId <> t.aId))
```

This says:

Show me all the distinct values of `aId` such that none of the rows with different values of `aId` contain a `bId` value such that there is not even one row with that `bId` and the same `aId`.

Comment: I tried your query with the data in my sqlfiddle, it returned 1, 2, and 5, but it should only return 1 and 5. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2905/3